# Is there a tool that I can use to create a diagram of my system's architecture?

Tags: hardware, cpu, cpu-architecture

I'm looking for a tool that can create both graphical files as well as text based ASCII representations of my system's CPU & motherboard architectures.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recently came across this tool called `lstopo` that's bundled in the package `hwloc` (at least on Fedora 19, that's where it was located). This tool seems to have everything one would want and more.

Here are a couple of samples. The first is a graphical representation that is outputted when you run the tool without any switches.

```
$ lstopo
```

*PNG screenshot*

[image: png]

```
$ lstopo --output-format txt -v --no-io --no-legend > lstopo.txt
```

*ASCII screennshot*

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Machine (7782MB)                       │
│                                        │
│ ┌────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │ Socket P#0                         │ │
│ │                                    │ │
│ │ ┌────────────────────────────────┐ │ │
│ │ │ L3 (3072KB)                    │ │ │
│ │ └────────────────────────────────┘ │ │
│ │                                    │ │
│ │ ┌──────────────┐  ┌──────────────┐ │ │
│ │ │ L2 (256KB)   │  │ L2 (256KB)   │ │ │
│ │ └──────────────┘  └──────────────┘ │ │
│ │                                    │ │
│ │ ┌──────────────┐  ┌──────────────┐ │ │
│ │ │ L1d (32KB)   │  │ L1d (32KB)   │ │ │
│ │ └──────────────┘  └──────────────┘ │ │
│ │                                    │ │
│ │ ┌──────────────┐  ┌──────────────┐ │ │
│ │ │ L1i (32KB)   │  │ L1i (32KB)   │ │ │
│ │ └──────────────┘  └──────────────┘ │ │
│ │                                    │ │
│ │ ┌──────────────┐  ┌──────────────┐ │ │
│ │ │ Core P#0     │  │ Core P#2     │ │ │
│ │ │              │  │              │ │ │
│ │ │ ┌──────────┐ │  │ ┌──────────┐ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ PU P#0   │ │  │ │ PU P#2   │ │ │ │
│ │ │ └──────────┘ │  │ └──────────┘ │ │ │
│ │ │ ┌──────────┐ │  │ ┌──────────┐ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ PU P#1   │ │  │ │ PU P#3   │ │ │ │
│ │ │ └──────────┘ │  │ └──────────┘ │ │ │
│ │ └──────────────┘  └──────────────┘ │ │
│ └────────────────────────────────────┘ │
└────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

But these represent just the basics of what you can do with this tool. If you were to consult the man page nearly every aspect of the output can be customized and disabled if needed to change the output to suit whatever needs you may have.

Just to give you a sense of what you can enable and disable.

```
   --no-caches
          Do not show caches.
   --no-useless-caches
          Do not show caches which do not have a hierarchical impact.
   --no-icaches
          Do not show Instruction caches, only Data and Unified caches are
          displayed.
   --merge
          Do not show levels that do not have a hierarchical impact.
   --restrict <cpuset>
          Restrict the topology to the given cpuset.
   --restrict binding
          Restrict the topology to the current process binding.  This option
         requires the use of the actual current machine topology (or any 
         other  topology  with
   --no-io
          Do not show any I/O device or bridge.  By default, common devices 
          (GPUs, NICs, block devices, ...) and interesting bridges are 
        shown.
```

The list goes on, this is just to give you a sense.

#### Portable Hardware Locality (hwloc)

The project, [hwloc](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/), that provides this tool and many others is part of the [Open MPI Project](http://www.open-mpi.org/). The hwloc project is described as follows:

> The Portable Hardware Locality (hwloc) software package provides a portable abstraction (across OS, versions, architectures, ...) of the hierarchical topology of modern architectures, including NUMA memory nodes, sockets, shared caches, cores and simultaneous multithreading. It also gathers various system attributes such as cache and memory information as well as the locality of I/O devices such as network interfaces, InfiniBand HCAs or GPUs. It primarily aims at helping applications with gathering information about modern computing hardware so as to exploit it accordingly and efficiently.

The `lstopo` tool is one of many tools available through this project.